# Addressing "System.NullReference" Resharper warning in function

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

TLDR: How can I check "DeclaringType" for null without causing a further cascade of problems in the function?

I have a C# LINQ query that uses reflection to list all Areas, Controllers, and Actions in my MVC Project. It appears to work correctly. I have not encountered any actual errors in the output.

Resharper, however, is declaring a possible null reference warning (see screenshot). It is not a false flag because there is always the possibility that `Type MembershipInfo.DeclaringType` could be null. I went with Resharper's suggestions of fixing the code (Check expression for null or Use Conditional Access). Neither approach helped.

[image: Resharper null reference warning]

I have even tried splitting apart the function and running a for-each loop to detect and change null into an empty string, but because even that for-each loop depends on a possibly null variable, I still get the same Resharper warning.

My workaround is to simply ignore the warning, but I was wondering if there is a way to check for null that doesn't cause even more cascading issues? If this were T-SQL I could easily place a `case` or `where statement` in the query; alas, I am unable to work that approach here.

```
private static IEnumerable<RwsPagelistViewModel> ActionLevelPermissionList()
{
    var projectName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.Split(',')[0];

    var asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MvcApplication));

    var list = 
        asm.GetTypes().
        SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public))
        .Where(d => d.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult")
        .Select(n => new
        {
            Area = n.DeclaringType.Namespace.ToString()
            .Replace(projectName + ".", "")
            .Replace("Areas.", "")
            .Replace(".Controllers", "")
            .Replace("Controllers", ""),
            Controller = n.DeclaringType != null ? n.DeclaringType.Name.Replace("Controller", "") : null,
            Action = n.Name,
            Attributes = string.Join(",", n.GetCustomAttributes().Select(a => a.GetType().Name.Replace("Attribute", ""))),
            AuthorizedRole = AuthorizedRole(n.CustomAttributes)
        })
        .Where(z => z.Attributes.Contains("RoleAuthorize"))
        .Select(y => new RwsPagelistViewModel
            {
                Area = y.Area,
                Controller = y.Controller,
                Action = y.Action,
                AuthorizedRole = y.AuthorizedRole
            });
    return list;
}
```

Comment: @Hosch250 -- I had to make a further tweak, but it appears this is the solution. I'm showing the answer below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking how to fix a specific warning, not for any and all feedback about the code. In other words, this question is not a request for a code review.

Answer (score 1):

@Hosch250's idea was the inspiration for what I'm posting as the answer. [Edited after comments.]

```
Area = (n.DeclaringType?.Namespace ?? string.Empty)
```

Problem solved: no more Resharper errors and the output still works as intended.

Comment: Or make it an extension method.